# MY SQL Query for thread messaging inbox and sent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I'm trying to create the thread messaging system in the PHP and mySQL. My messaging table is as follow

```
SELECT `es_id`, `es_fid`, `es_tid`, `es_subject`, `es_message`, `es_onstamp`, `es_msg_read`, `es_f_del`, `es_t_del`, `threadid` FROM `esb2b_messages`
```

In this table

```
es_id = primary key for the table.
es_fid = This field store the from user id.
es_tid = This field store the to user id.
es_subject = This field store the subject of message.
es_message = This field store the body of message.
es_onstamp = This field store the time stamp.
es_msg_read = This field store if receiver open the message.
es_f_del = This field store if the from user delete this message.
es_t_del = This field store the the to user delete this message.
threadid = This field store the id of parent message(es_id of the replied message).
```

Please refer this image for clear understanding what i want to archive.

http://oi59.tinypic.com/2wdav45.jpg

In the picture above the combination of these 4 messages create one thread.

What query should be for the inbox and for sent item. Right now I'm using this query for inbox but every message is separate.

```
SELECT `es_id`, `es_fid`, `es_tid`, `es_subject`, `es_message`, `es_onstamp`, `es_msg_read`, `es_f_del`, `es_t_del`, `threadid` FROM `esb2b_messages` WHERE `es_tid`= UNHEX('$Loginuser') ORDER BY `esb2b_messages`.`es_onstamp` DESC
```

Please also see this image to see what is output right now and what i want.

Please note: inbox should be sorted and display only by last message received in thread. Same sent item should be sorted and displayed only by last message sent in thread.

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `esb2b_messages` (
  `es_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `es_fid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `es_tid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `es_subject` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `es_message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `es_tempdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `es_onstamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `es_msg_read` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `es_f_del` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `es_t_del` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `threadid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`es_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=367 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `esb2b_messages`
--

INSERT INTO `esb2b_messages` (`es_id`, `es_fid`, `es_tid`, `es_subject`, `es_message`, `es_tempdate`, `es_onstamp`, `es_msg_read`, `es_f_del`, `es_t_del`, `threadid`) VALUES
(361, 3, 23, ' Quotation for Embossed and watermark Certificate Printing', 'Hello, this is Bella, we specilized in providing variable data printing services for eight years and we can make it according to your detail requests. Could you please send your original artpaper sothat we can discuss it in details? Looking forward to hearing from you soon. My skype is kingwin1688.', '2014-08-23 22:40:39', '2014-08-23 21:59:55', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', '0'),
(360, 2, 23, 'test', 'asgdfgdfsgdf', '2014-08-23 19:39:11', '2014-08-19 02:35:09', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', '0'),
(363, 2, 23, 'not threaded', 'asgdfgdfsgdf', '2014-08-23 23:29:28', '2014-08-19 02:35:09', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', '0'),
(362, 23, 2, ' Quotation for Embossed and watermark Certificate Printing', 'Hello, this is Bella, we specilized in providing variable data printing services for eight years and we can make it according to your detail requests. Could you please send your original artpaper sothat we can discuss it in details? Looking forward to hearing from you soon. My skype is kingwin1688.', '2014-08-23 19:39:15', '2014-08-23 21:59:55', 'No', 'No', 'No', '0'),
(364, 23, 2, 'reply', 'my first reply', '2014-08-23 21:41:11', '2014-08-23 02:35:09', 'No', 'No', 'No', '360'),
(365, 2, 23, 'this is reply of reply', 'reply of reply', '2014-08-23 22:41:26', '2014-08-24 02:35:09', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', '360'),
(366, 23, 2, 'reply', 'my first reply', '2014-08-23 21:41:11', '2014-08-24 02:35:09', 'No', 'No', 'No', '360');
```

Link to sql fiddle
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9def4/1/0

The es_fid and es_tid are foreign key for the user table.

The output for inbox should be

From | Subject | Message | TimeStamp

In group

Let me explain how this system work, if the 'threadid' is 0 this mean the row is parent. if the 'threadid' in row is not zero it means it is child to one parent. i want whenever user goes to inbox it only display latest received in child if exits else display parent.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the output you expect?

Comment: It should be same as Gmail, the message which have same es_id and threadid should be displayed once. In the inbox the most recent received should be display and in sent the most recent sent should be displayed as thread to all other messages in the group.

Comment: Pleas view this picture http://s2.postimg.org/mw1m72zk9/output.jpg

Comment: Just the 2 rows that you enclosed in red or all 4 rows? Also the expected result columns are "From", "Subject", "Message", "Received" is that correct? If so where is the "From" column coming from? It isn't on the table that you posted.

Comment: Could you post the CREATE statement for that table and a few INSERTs of sample data so that we can target the result you're after (hit export in phpmyadmin)

Comment: If you can give the CREATE statements for each of the tables involved in the query that we will have to write that would help, or at least the names of the tables and the columns. Also a few INSERTs and expected output in the form of a series of columns and rows.

Comment: Please use http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9def4/1/0

Comment: @FaizRasool are you there can we discuss about this your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9def4/13/0

```
select es_id, es_fid, es_subject, es_message, es_onstamp
  from esb2b_messages x
 where threadid = 0
   and es_tid = 23
   and not exists (select 1
          from esb2b_messages y
         where y.threadid = x.es_id
           and y.es_tid = x.es_tid)
union all
select es_id, es_fid, es_subject, es_message, es_onstamp
  from esb2b_messages x
 where threadid <> 0
   and es_tid = 23
   and es_onstamp = (select max(y.es_onstamp)
                       from esb2b_messages y
                      where y.threadid = x.threadid)
 order by es_id, seq, es_onstamp
```

360 is now reduced to the latest child as discussed in comments.

The other threads have no children, so the parent is shown. If they did have children, the latest child would be shown.

Comment: I need 2 query one for inbox and one for sent item, Assume for inbox (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9def4/3) use this conditions to get inbox `es_tid`='23' and for the sent use this conditions to get the outbox `es_fid`='23'. In the fiddle i have posted you will see the ES_ID 360 and 365 is part of one thread due to ED_ID 365 contains the threadid of 360. I want to show the only latest version of thread.

Comment: See my edit. It would help significantly if you post the output you're expecting. What do you mean the "latest version of the thread"?

Comment: Please see this image. http://s28.postimg.org/k96ymr6yz/new_clear.jpg. I want it as one row. that is only the upper one. es_id 365 one

Comment: ok let me explain how this system work, if the 'threadid' is 0 this mean the row is parent. if the 'threadid' in row is not zero it means it is child to one parent. i want whenever user goes to inbox it only display latest received in child if exits else display parent.

Comment: I get the parent/child thing, which the query above achieves. However if it brought back only the latest child of each parent (where there is a child), wouldn't that be the 2nd of the 2 rows in your image? The first row is a parent and the second is the only child. That would make the only child the latest child.

Comment: yes it is the on which have the subject of "this is reply of reply". Please update your query . thanks for help mate

Comment: you are the star man. just a quick fix, if you can fix the ES_ID of child which is 365 instead of 360

Comment: Just changed it to ES_ID. I did that originally to place the children beneath the parents (grouping the rows into the threads they reflect). If you write any other queries where you want multiple threads with the children underneath each, you can use that as a trick to establish the order. In this case since you're just pulling back one row per thread it doesn't provide much of a benefit.

Comment: The "SEQ" column I had added was for the same purpose by the way, so that can be gotten rid of as well